# OS VectorMap Local Layer Definition Files

Tags: geospatial, data-format

Would anybody be kind enough to share their QIGS Layer Definition Files for the following OS VectorMap Local layers. SLD file formats would work as well. Alternativly, where do you buy your OS VML data from? The site I got mine don't have the files I need yet.

Boundary_Line

Building_Area

Building_Line

Building_Text

Countour_Line

Height_Point

Height_Text

Landform_Area

Landform_Line

Misc_Text

Point_Misc

Road_Line

Road_Text

RoadCLine

Settlement_Area

Settlement_Line

Vegetation_Area

Water_Area

Water_Line

Water_Point

Water_Text

Woodland_Area

Comment: do you mean QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a link to the official Ordnance Survey Stylesheets hosted on Github. They also do ones for VectorMap District which is the open data version

https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OS-VectorMap-Local-stylesheets